# React-native restart an application on user sign up

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react-native application whose top level `App.js` is as follows:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(

    { Landing, SignUpWithGoogle },

    { 
          initialRouteName  : 'Landing' 
        , navigationOptions : {
            header : null
        }
    }
);


const AppStack = createStackNavigator(

    {   
          AppContainer
        , Campaign
        , Compose
    },

    { 
          initialRouteName  : 'AppContainer' 
        , navigationOptions : {
            header : null
        }
    }
);


/**
    @TODO: 
        force app to reload on user creation ... 

        there needs to be a state transition on user creation
        ... not sure how to 
*/
class App extends React.Component {

    render () {

        const stack = (!this.props.authenticating && this.props.user)
            ? <AppStack  {...this.props} />
            : <AuthStack />


        return (
            <Loader
                isLoaded        = { !this.props.authenticating && this.props.feedIsLoaded}
                imageSource     = {logo}
                backgroundStyle = {loading.loadingBackgroundStyle}
            >
                {stack}
            </Loader>
        )

    }
}
```

There is a `Loader` component from https://github.com/TheSavior/react-native-mask-loader that hides the app with a splash page until the app has fetched user authentication data, or determined that this is a new user. This works great except in the case when the user signs up for the first time, then the app just jumps right into authenticated mode, and **fails to load initial data** that I want for the new user. The only to get around this is to restart the app, which is a no go. Is there a way to transition between `AuthStack` and `AppStack` better so that the information I want on signup are all there? One way would be to force `reload` the app so that we are directed back to the `Loader` screen and state, but it's unclear how this can be done.

Comment: You could stick with AuthStack itself on user sign up time, ie let AuthStack and AppStack share common routes except for login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this for my use case.

```
const Routes =  {
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Status: {
    screen: Status,
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,  // To prevent swipeback
    },
  },
...
};

const LoggedRootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...Routes
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Status'
  }
)

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...Routes
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
)
```

For passing props use [Redux](https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053) for keeping a global state. You can connect your components to redux state to access the props. Hope this helps

Comment: is there a way to implement this without redux?